# ¿Donde esta el error al insertar en mi base de datos desde android con ayuda de retrofit 2.3.0?

Tags: android, base-de-datos, retrofit

Hola estoy haciendo  un app  donde tengo que insertar datos en una tabla de base de datos , hasta el momento solo estoy haciendo pruebas para  ver como funciona retrofit , la cuestion es que  ya realize un ejemplo  donde  tengo que insertar solo id, nombre , y apellido en la tabla, el id es autoincrement, y solo el nombre   y el apellido   lo mando desde un formulario , ya tengo definida mi interface con con  su respectivo endpoint  y la clase modelo para la respuesta en json que solo recibe una un estatus con su respectivo valor para mostrarlo en un toast,

al presionar el boton de registro me sale este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy usando SLIM 2 para la API

aqui esta la funcion

```
$app->post('alta/:nombre/:apellidos', function($nombre,$apellidos) use ($app){
$conexion = getConnection();
$sql = "INSERT INTO tabla_comodin(nombre,apellidos) VALUES (:nombre,:apellidos)";
$consulta = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$consulta->bindParam("nombre",$nombre);
$consulta->bindparam("apellidos",$apellidos);
$consulta->execute();

if ($consulta->rowCount()!=0){
            echo '{"estatus":"Este es una prueba desde el nuevo sistema con el metodo POST"}';
    }else{
        echo '{"estatus":"NO se pudo registrar el contactos"}';
    }
$conexion = null;
```

});

Comment: Jesus, si publicaras el codigo seria mucho mejor para nosotros para copiar el codigo y formular las respuestas. Asi con imagenes se nos hace mucho mas incomodo.

Answer (score 1):

En tu clase `registrar()` le pasas dos argumentos:

`registrar(String nombre, String apellidos)`

En el mismo método si vamos hacia abajo tienes la linea:

`Call<Resultado> call = servicio.pepe(nombre, apellido);`

O sea que estas pasando un argumento incorrecto, reemplaza:

`Call<Resultado> call = servicio.pepe(nombre, apellidos);`

Answer (score 0):

Debes de marcar los campos con el attribute @SerializeName para que el serializador pueda asignar el valor del json.

Por ejemplo si la respuesta del servidor es

```
{ "estatus_22": "Datos guardados"}
```

La clase `resultado` deberia de tener el campo `estatus` marcado de la siguiente manera:

```
public class resultado
{

 @SerializeName("status_22")
  private String status;


  public void setStatus(String status)
  {
    this.status = status;
  }

  public String getStatus()
  {
    return this.status;
  }
}
```

Comment: Gracias Einer, ya lo probé así y me sigue apareciendo el mismo error e incluso agregue `@expose` y no, porcierto disculpas por publicar  imagenes

Comment: Ya  lo pude resolver , era un error  en la función que publique ,  gracias  a @Einer tu respuesta también me sirvió

Comment: Excelente, me alegra saber que pudiste seguir adelante.